# Can you create a user-defined "resource" variable?

Tags: php

The following code will create a `resource` variable and have it point to a file object:

```
$file = fopen("1.txt", "w");
```

But can you create a user-defined `resource` variable and have it point to a user-defined object for example?

Comment: Are you looking for custom stream wrapper as in https://www.php.net/manual/en/stream.streamwrapper.example-1.php?

Answer (score 0):

Resources aren't pointers to something else that exists in your PHP program, they are a pointer to something *outside* PHP. As [the manual page about them](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.resource.php) puts it:

> A resource is a special variable, holding a reference to an external resource.

In the example you give, somewhere in the definition of the `fopen` function, which is written in C, a system call is made that allocates a "file handle" - an identifier that can be used to refer to the opened file in later C code. That could just be passed to you as a number, but it's not a number you want to be manipulating - or for attackers to be able to manipulate on your shared hosting.

So instead, PHP wraps the value in a particular structure, which you can pass around like any other value in PHP, but can't manipulate. All you can do is pass it to some other function that knows what to do with it, such as `fwrite` or `fread`.

Resources are one of the oldest types in PHP, older than objects. In modern PHP, the same role can be taken by a built-in object, which can have private data associated with it which is invisible to PHP, but then add class hierarchies, methods, and properties which make use of that private data inside. That's how PHP implements [XML DOM functionality](https://php.net/dom), for instance - there's a hidden pointer inside every DOM-related object pointing to a completely different representation of the XML document.

There is a current project to slowly move away from resources to objects. For instance, there's now [a `CurlHandle` class](https://www.php.net/CurlHandle) replacing the resource that [`curl_init()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-init.php) used to return. To be clear, this doesn't involve an object wrapping a resource, or a resource pointing to an object; both are just wrappers for something else, specific to the curl library code.